# fit element's position/size to other element's position/size

Tags: jquery, position, size, parent-child

I'm working on a layout with images that will be positioned absolutely on top of each other, while each image should show a colored box with text on hover.

As I don't know the images' sizes/ratios, they get diverse max-width/max-height values with diverse top/left/right/bottom values. Such as:

```
img {
    position: absolute;
}

img.1 {
    max-width: 80%;
    max-height: 74%;
    left: 8%;
    top: 11%;
}

img.2 {
    max-width: 88%;
    max-height: 82%;
    left: 4%;
    top: 7%;
}...
```

Now on hover each image should display a container on top with a colored background + text. On click image + container should disappear, showing the underneath one.

I thought I could put a wrapper around the img and the info-container, while the container will only show on hover. But therefor, the parent wrapper has to take the actual size of the image.

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <img />
    <div class="info">Info</div>
</div>
```

Another option would be to have each img followed by its info-container, which will get the same size/position as its previous img.

```
<img />
<div class="info">Info</div> <–– Somehow same size as previous img
```

Anybody knows how to solve this with CSS (+jQuery?)?

Thanks!

Comment: Absolute positioning is going to change how width propagates to its parent element. You can try a `relative` positioned `div` inside an `absolute` positioned div, then have a *non-absolute* `img` expand the relative div.  This will cause subsequent div's width inside the relative div to behave as you'd expect.

Comment: I placed a `relative` wrapper (containing img + info-container) inside the `absolute` wrapper, which still does not take the image's size. Either I didn't really understand :) or it does not serve what I need. Couldn't I set the wrapper's size to 100%/100% via CSS, that the images take their correct max-width/max-height and have jQuery to adjust the wrapper's size to the img's size?

Comment: You can use jQuery/JavaScript to accomplish this.  As far as doing it with CSS, make sure you're not using absolute positioning on the img itself (only on an outside div), and place both the img and the Info div inside the relative div (which is inside an absolute div).

Comment: Now, I tried giving the wrappers an absolute position with diverse top/left values and 100% height 100% width, in order that the images get their right sizes (max-width/height). I put this small jQuery to it `$('article.item').css('height',$("this").children("img").height());`, for adjusting the wrapper's height to its child img. But unfortunately nothing of this works out. Does anyone have some more tips, I'm quite confused about this?!

Answer (score 0):

So, the method that worked for me the best, was to not wrap the img's and place them (position: absolute) together with a max-width/max-height. Each image is followed by the (to be overlayed) .item-info (position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0;).

jQuery updates each .item-info to the size and position of its respective (previous) img-element:

```
  function adjustItemInfo() {

    $(".thumbnail-class").each(function() {

      $(this).next().css({
        'height': $(this).height(),
        'width': $(this).width(),
        'top': $(this).css( "top" ),
        'left': $(this).css( "left" ),
        'bottom': $(this).css( "bottom" ),
        'right': $(this).css( "right" )
      })

    });

  }

  adjustItemInfo();

  $(window).resize(function(){
    adjustItemInfo();
  })
```